# Komma bei "Besonders dann wenn" am Satzanfang

Tags: comma

Kommt bei

> Besonders dann wenn es dunkel ist, sollte man die Scheinwerfer einschalten.

ein Komma zwischen "dann" und "wenn"? Also:

> Besonders dann, wenn es dunkel ist, sollte man die Scheinwerfer einschalten.

Bitte mit Erklärung.

Comment: Ja. Ein Beispiel in einer angesehen Quelle. https://deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/wenn-varianten-selbst-wenn-ausser-wenn-es-sei-denn-sonst-andernfalls/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In der Konstruktion deines Beispiels handelt es sich bei

> wenn es dunkel ist

um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz, der vorne und hinten mit einem Komma einzuschließen ist.

Das (vordere) Komma entfällt beim geänderten Satz:

> Wenn es dunkel ist, sollte man ...

weil der Nebensatz nach vorne nicht mehr abgetrennt zu werden braucht.